# Wireless not working on a Dell XPS 15

Tags: 10.10, wireless, drivers

I have a dell XPS 15 running windows 7, I recently installed ubuntu 10.10. The Ubuntu OS detects my Bluetooth card but not my wireless internet card.

Initially I could browse the internet through a wired internet connection but after a recent update even that has stopped working. During boot up I logged on to a previous generic release and thats how I'm able to access wired internet connections now but wireless is still out.

Any idea how I can get back wireless and wired connections to work on the latest release?

I tried installing a synaptic package for the wireless cards through synaptic manager, some linux kernel files were installed. Ever since then I have not been able to connect to the internet. It was on release-28.

I currently log into the release-27 in the GRUB bootloader to use the net.

I´m pretty new to linux so the details that I provide as such maybe incomplete.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at this question and then edit your question adding more detail? http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 2):

The XPS15 comes with a Intel Centrino Wireless-n 1030 which requires a minimum of linux kernel 2.6.36 ( http://intellinuxwireless.org/ ). You could simply update your kernel to 2.6.37 and it will get detected. Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this site and get it detected ...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11128570#post11128570

look for tachidok's solutions

Comment: Please put the fix and link to the source.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

It works on 13.10, just run the updates so the wifi doesn't drop out.

Comment: Can you be more specific?